# raise URLError(err) urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [Errno -2] Name or service not known>

Tags: python, pytube

I'm having this error when running my python file and I don't know how to fix it

here is the code

```
import time 
from pytube import YouTube

vid = YouTube('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7YwNjB1kd0s')

print(vid.length)
```

Here is how i executed the file

```
python3  main.py
```

Here is the Error log

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/urllib/request.py", line 1348, in do_open
    h.request(req.get_method(), req.selector, req.data, headers,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/http/client.py", line 1282, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/http/client.py", line 1328, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/http/client.py", line 1277, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/http/client.py", line 1037, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/http/client.py", line 975, in send
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/http/client.py", line 1447, in connect
    super().connect()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/http/client.py", line 941, in connect
    self.sock = self._create_connection(
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/socket.py", line 824, in create_connection
    for res in getaddrinfo(host, port, 0, SOCK_STREAM):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/socket.py", line 955, in getaddrinfo
    for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
socket.gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/premium/Desktop/linux_python101/downloadvideo.py", line 6, in <module>
    print(vid.length)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pytube/__main__.py", line 383, in length
    return int(self.vid_info.get('videoDetails', {}).get('lengthSeconds'))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pytube/__main__.py", line 246, in vid_info
    innertube_response = innertube.player(self.video_id)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pytube/innertube.py", line 300, in player
    return self._call_api(endpoint, query, self.base_data)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pytube/innertube.py", line 242, in _call_api
    response = request._execute_request(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pytube/request.py", line 37, in _execute_request
    return urlopen(request, timeout=timeout)  # nosec
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/urllib/request.py", line 216, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/urllib/request.py", line 519, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/urllib/request.py", line 536, in _open
    result = self._call_chain(self.handle_open, protocol, protocol +
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/urllib/request.py", line 496, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/urllib/request.py", line 1391, in https_open
    return self.do_open(http.client.HTTPSConnection, req,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/urllib/request.py", line 1351, in do_open
    raise URLError(err)
urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [Errno -2] Name or service not known>
```

I'm running Ubuntu and I'm not in a virtual environment
Running python3 and it would be greatly appreciated if you could help me.

Comment: Are you sure that you're connected to the internet and that your DNS settings are properly configured?

Comment: I get no errors running this.

Comment: Michael M - yes i did edit my DNS settings to use 1.1.1.1, but im not sure that's the problem